# Having issues with calculating a prompt answer

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create a prompt for the user to manually input scores. Issue is, the math involved isn't working like it should and treating the problem as a multiplication problem than a sum. Any idea if I have a bug or something of error on my end? Here's my whole code:

```
//Code Challenge 02

//Johns team will start on the calculation. 

johnTeam = 89 + 120 + 103;
newScore = johnTeam/3;
johnTeam = newScore;

//For the sake of mathematic sanity, lets put newScore to 0.
newScore = 0;

console.log(johnTeam + " scored this much in average.\n");

//Next is Mikes Team

mikeTeam = 116 + 94 + 123;
newScore = mikeTeam/3;
mikeTeam = newScore;

//Reset newScore
newScore = 0;

console.log(mikeTeam + " scored this much in average.\n");

//Lastly, Mary's Team

maryTeam = 97 + 134 + 105;
newScore = maryTeam/3;
maryTeam = newScore;

//Reset newScore
newScore = 0;

console.log(maryTeam + " scored this much in average.\n");

//Calculate on who won.
console.log("Round 1: Who won?\n");

//Lets make a big huge enormous if and else statements revolving around these teams.
if(johnTeam > mikeTeam && johnTeam > maryTeam)
{
    console.log("Johns team wins!");
}else if(mikeTeam > johnTeam && mikeTeam > maryTeam){
    console.log("Mikes Team wins!");
}else if(maryTeam > johnTeam && maryTeam > mikeTeam){
    console.log("Mary's Team wins!");
}else if(johnTeam === mikeTeam && johnTeam > maryTeam){
    console.log("John and Mike both tied!");
}else if(johnTeam === maryTeam && johnTeam > mikeTeam){
    console.log("John and Mary have both tied!");
}else if(mikeTeam === maryTeam && mikeTeam > johnTeam){
    console.log("Mike and Mary have both tied!");
}else{
    console.log("Everybody is a winner! Wowzerz!");
}
```

//***************************************************
    //Now that is over, ready for round 2? Lets try something more realistic, and not so generic.

```
//Reset all scores!

johnTeam = 0;
mikeTeam = 0;
maryTeam = 0;

console.log("\nInsert Johns score per question.");
var a = prompt("Insert first score.");
console.log(a);
var b = prompt("Insert second score,");
console.log(b);
var c = prompt("Insert third score.");
console.log(c);

johnTeam = a + b + c;
newScore = johnTeam/3;
johnTeam = newScore;

newScore = 0;

console.log(johnTeam + " scored this much in average.");
```

`

Objective: To add up three scores, then divide for the average score. Then decide which team has the higher score.

Issue: First part is fine. The prompt part is treating the equation like a multiplication problem.

Comment: `prompt()` returns a string, not a number. Try `parseInt( x, 10)` on the prompt strings.

Comment: Yes prompt() returns string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt
johnTeam = +a + +b + +c //Will sum the result

Comment: Learn to debug `console.log(johnTeam)`

Answer (score 0):

prompt() function returns a string, so you have to parse it like this:

```
parseInt('your string', 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns a string need to parse the results into integers to do the math on them:

> Result is a string containing the text entered by the user, or null.

```js
johnTeam = 0;
mikeTeam = 0;
maryTeam = 0;
console.log("\nInsert Johns score per question.");
johnTeam = parseInt(prompt("Insert first score."));
console.log(johnTeam);
mikeTeam = parseInt(prompt("Insert second score,"));
console.log(mikeTeam);
maryTeam = parseInt(prompt("Insert third score."));
console.log(maryTeam);
newScore = (maryTeam + mikeTeam + johnTeam) / 3
console.log(newScore + " scored this much in average.");
```